# Negative number squared in expression $-5-8^{2}$

Tags: exponentiation

I know this probably is a silly stupid question, but I just don't get it. I'm currently doing Khan Academy pre-algebra and stumbled upon an awkward problem.
I assume that:

$-5-8^{2}=59$

Because -8 squared is 64 and et cetera. But the right answer is actually -69. I sincerely don't get why. I told my wife, she's sure it should be 59 too. Can someone explain to me how comes it is -69?

Comment: $-5-8^2=-5-64$ while $-5+(-8)^2=-5+64$...

Comment: You probably thought something like "$-5-8^2 = -5+(-8^2)$. Now $-8^2 = -1 * 8^2$, which is equal to $-64$, and not $64$, since order of operations means you square the $8$ first before multiplying by $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct order of the operations is: first calculate the powers than add the results. So in you case:
$$-5-8^2=-5-(8^2)=-5-64=-69$$

Answer (score 1):

It's just convention in the priority of the operations.  Exponents are done before any addition/substraction If we add brackets, your expression becomes:

$$
( -5 )- ( 8^2 )
$$

Thus it is $-69$.

Why was that chose?  Simple, as you said in you answer, there is no difference between $(-8)^2$ and $8^2$ so $(-5) + ((-8)^2)$ could just have been written $(-5) + (8^2)$.  Not as interesting as the other priority order.